# Refactor using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a simple interface with methods such as

```
     bool TryGetValue(string key, out string value);
     bool TryGetValue(string key, out int value);
     bool TryGetValue(string key, out double value);
     bool TryGetValue(string key, out DateTime value);
     // only value types allowed 

     //with the implementation based on dictionary<string, object> 
     bool TryGetValue(string key, out string value)
     {
        object rc;
        if ( dict.TryGetValue(key, out rc) )
        {
            value = rc.ToString();
            return true;
        }

        value = null;
        return false;
     }
```

Looks like a perfect case for generics as

```
     bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value) where T: ValueType;
```

except not able to work out the func implementation, anyone ?

UPDATE - the following does not compile, i'd like to avoid creating multiple TryGet... funcs !

```
     bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value)
     {
         return dict.TryGetValue(key, out value) ;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value) where T : struct
{
  object obj;
  var result = dict.TryGetValue(key, out obj);
  value = (T)obj;
  return result;
}
```

It' not pretty, but deals with the limitations of `out`...maybe someone can shorten it even more?  If so *please* comment...always up to learn new ways.

Comment: @Kumar - Updated the answer...hopefully that's what you're after, if not please let me know what you're missing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that what you want is this:

```
 bool TryGetValue<TValue>(string key, out TValue value)
 {
    object rc;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out rc))
    {
        value = (TValue)rc;
        return true;
    }

    value = default(TValue);
    return false;
 }
```

This doesn't actually *convert* the values if they are the wrong type - it assumes that the generic `System.Object` instances sitting in the dictionary are actually of type `TValue` when the `TryGetValue` method is invoked.

If you want to restrict the method to only allow value types for the generic parameter, just change the method signature to this:

```
 bool TryGetValue<TValue>(string key, out TValue value) where TValue : struct
```

*Note - JaredPar had the first answer but seems to have deleted his, so I am undeleting mine because I think it's what the OP wanted.  I apologize for any unintended duplication.*

Comment: It would probably be better to return `false` rather than throwing an InvalidCastException when there is an object associated with the key, but it's the wrong type.

Comment: @Anon: I can see it both ways.  If you return `false` then the dictionary is lying to you; it says it doesn't have the key, but it really does.  If you have a typical `if (!lookup.TryGetValue(key, out value)) { lookup.Add(key, newValue) }` then it would fail unexpectedly.  It depends on how this class is going to be used, though, I can see some situations in which simply returning `false` would be the desired result.

Comment: that would work, to avoid the scenario you describe in comments, any way to declare dictionary<string,T> where T: ValueType without subclassing ?

Comment: @Kumar: You can add a restriction to the `TryGetValue` method to restrict the output.  You can add the same restriction to your `Add` method (assuming there is one) to restrict what goes *into* the dictionary.  But you can't create an instance of `Dictionary<string, ValueType>` if that's what you're trying to do.  Even with subclassing, if you create a `Dictionary<string, T> where T : ValueType` then it can only store the exact type `T` as the value, you can't throw any old `object` into it, which according to your question is what you need to be able to do.

Comment: Sorry, I can't believe I wrote `where T : ValueType`... twice!  The correct keyword is `struct`, I've corrected this.

Comment: good answer but Nick Craver has the cleaner/shorter code
... but +1 for the default keyword

Comment: @Aaronaught - If you look in reflector `Dictionary<T,TValue>` already outputs a `default(TValue)` in your out param if the key isn't found, no need to assign it :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yep, I know, I make good use of that behaviour and in practice I'd write this the same way you did.  I wrote it a bit different for this answer just to make it as clear as possible what was going on.  I'd add a second, more compact version, but then I'd just be duplicating your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx it may prove useful to you.  Also why not just extend Dictionary?

Comment: business rule - has to be basic value types only

Comment: Umm, you'll have to forgive me on this one, but basic value types would be what?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx  That is what msdn says about value types (structs/enums)  with User-defined being one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Aaronaught has caught the main crux of the problem (capturing the `object` and casting/unboxing to `T`), but some additional points:

- to limit to value-types(*), you use `where T : struct`, not `where T : ValueType`...
- ...but note that `string` is *not* a value-type, so this probably isn't a good "fit"
- ...and (*=) note that `where T : struct` also excludes `Nullable<T>`

So I think you just need to remove that constraint completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go for something like this, although as Marc points out the `struct` constraint won't allow strings:

```
private static class Container<T> where T : struct
{
    public static Dictionary<string, T> Dict = new Dictionary<string, T>();
}

public bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value) where T : struct
{
    return Container<T>.Dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extension method.**

```
namespace AssemblyCSharp
{
    public static class ExtentionMethod {

        public static bool TryGetValue<T, T2>(this Dictionary<T, T2> dict, string key, out T value) {
            return dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
    }
}
```